# Как называется данный элемент

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Ребят, как сделать эти точки над кнопкой? Может есть какая-то view?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из под коробки такого элемента нет. Но начать можно отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586619/android-viewpager-with-bottom-dots

Comment: Контейнер для прокрутки ViewPager, а точки это TabLayout

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в лейаут:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/photos_viewpager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

В активити:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.photos_viewpager);
PagerAdapter adapter = new PhotosAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), photosUrl);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager, true);
```

Создайте точки:
1) selected_dot.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="8dp"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </shape>    
</item>
```

2) default_dot.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="8dp"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </shape>    
</item>
```

3) tab_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_dot"
      android:state_selected="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_dot"/>
```

И добавьте точки в `TabLayout`:

```
app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
app:tabGravity="center"
app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
```